# Lubuntu laptop smart/custom charging

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, battery, smart, charging

I want to make a home server out of my Asus 11.6" laptop with Lubuntu installed.
I don't know how charging process happens on this device with Lubuntu, however I am pretty sure how it should be charged for my needs. I am looking for kinda smart/customized charging in order to maximize battery lifetime.

So I want to have my laptop always powered with the cable (plugged into grid) so battery remains only for cases when there is no electricity (like UPS). I don't want my battery to be topped up to 100% always. I want to start charging when it gets discharged down to 20% of capacity naturally, and charge it only up to 80% of maximum capacity.

I am tech savvy so I need just hints and direction point where to look in.

And thank you very much for your answers in advance.

Comment: Changing is controlled by the hardware, mediated by the firmware (UEFI/BIOS) and its specific settings, namely changing thresholds *may* eventually be set/changed by some proprietary software (Windows only and AFAIK only Lenovo provides such thing). There's nothing that can be done from the OS, other than the aforementioned exception, to achieve what you want. Actually not even in the few Lenovo laptops that can run such software it'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So I found required information on my own.

This is called "start and stop thresholds" for battery charging. Not all brands of laptops support this feature in the linux.

I've found some workarounds, as well as TLP utility. TLP has all kinds of power saving functionalities including battery care. Since v1.4 the number of supported laptops has increased in TLP's battery care functionality (ThinkPads, Asus, Huawei Matebooks, LG Gram, Samsung), but not to the full extent.

I managed to set only "stop" threshold for my Asus 11.6" X207N. Sadly but it doesn't have an option to set "start" threshold using available workarounds or TLP. I needed as well to upgrade my Lubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 to have 5.17+ kernel version in order for required config entry appeared in the system.

I used following articles:
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/02/how-to-limit-battery-charging-set.html
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/06/easily-set-charging-thresholds-for-asus.html

I am not really satisfied with the result, however I got something. It's not perfect, but it will make my battery living significantly longer. So now I hope Lubuntu/Ubuntu developers will add full battery care functionality for Asus laptops in the future.

Comment: Your (too high) expectations are based on a mistake. The ASUS hardware does *not* provide a start charge threshold. You can wait forever for a software solution.